# CSRF token generation issue

Tags: java, struts-1

To prevent CSRF below were the steps i have followed:

**1**. First time when request comes(to loginfilter) session is null, create a session add token(randome number) to this new session by using setAttribute() and redirect to login.jsp screen using **dispatcher.forward**.

**2**. in login.jsp screen use getAttribute() store the token in the hidden filed.

**3**. on submit of login.jsp first request will come to loginfilter, here compare the token from the request with the token in the session, if matches then proceed with  executing the action class. otherwise generate the new token for the same session and redirect to the login.jsp using **sendRedirect()**

when i ran the security tool on this application, i message saying "Missing one time token parameter".

Please help me.

---

**1.filter.java**

```
if (session == null) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
else {
    // validate the CSRF
    String sToken = httprequest.getSession().getAttribute("CSRF_TOKEN")
            .toString();
    String pToken = httprequest.getParameter("CSRF_TOKEN");
    System.out.println("Tokens - " + sToken + pToken);
    if (sToken.equals(pToken)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else {
        CommonUtils.updateSessionToken(session);
        /*
         * RequestDispatcher rd =
         * request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
         * rd.forward(request, response);
         */
        httpresponse.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

---

**2.login.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
    Object token = request.getSession().getAttribute("CSRF_TOKEN");
    String tokenStr = "";
    if (token != null) {
        tokenStr = (String) token;
    }

    System.out.println("+tokenStr " + tokenStr);
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CSRFGuard Test Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome to the OWASP CSRFGuard Test Application! Where would you like
    to go?
    <br />
    <form action="/CSRF/helloServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" /> <br /> <input type="text"
            value="<%=tokenStr%>" name="CSRF_TOKEN" /> <input type="submit"
            value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**3.web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>CSRF</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>Hell0oServelt</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloServelt</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServelt</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

        <listener>
        <listener-class>com.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>LoggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.LoggedInFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**4.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener**

---

```
public class CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        System.out.println("New session id - "+session.getId());
        String tokenId = generateRandomId();
    session.setAttribute("CSRF_TOKEN", tokenId);
    System.out.println("newtoken -"+tokenId);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        /** nothing to do  **/
    }

}
```

**5.HelloServlet**

---

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome ...!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

On redirect the browser is simply instructed to make a new request to login.jsp. This login page would not have the token set in hidden field unless you are using some framework which can help you with that. So instead use request dispatcher forward. Also you mentioned that you ran a security tool. If it is a tool which mimics requests then make sure to include the token in the replay second request or it will not be recognized.

**EDIT** (After code was posted):
I did not get the reasoning of using a listener. What you wanted to achieve is that whenever a session is created you automatically associate a token with it. This you can  do in your filter class as well. Please note that the httpRequest.getSession checks for the session and if not present it creates as well. There are other variants of this method which take boolean parameter. Also you need to understand that when you do chain.doFilter(request, response) it means that the request processing to proceed further in the chain.

You can take help from other popular CSRF filter implementations like  [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/filters/CsrfPreventionFilter.java) , [here](https://code.google.com/p/csrf-filter/source/browse/trunk/simple-csrf-filter/src/main/java/com/google/code/csrf/StatelessCookieFilter.java). Also you can take a look at sample posted  [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps)

Comment: when i used dispatcher forward i got message saying 'one time token value is ignored by the server', so i used redirect that message got resolved. i didnt got your sentence 'make sure to include the token in the replay second request or it will not be recognized.' will you please explore it more... please...

Comment: What security tool are you running? In the end everything is GET or POST request and according to you, each request goes through the filter. So you need to check when running security tool, what parameters are getting passed with POST request of login. The usual way with such tools is to first issue a GET request, then capture the csrf token from the response html by parsing it, and then issue the POST request with the same CSRF token. With these steps the login should succeed, but simply sending a POST request without CSRF would fail and that is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Tool is IBM appscan, All requests are POST only. i had enough logs and observed that for first request the tokens are matching, so it went to action classs from there because of invalid credentials it went back to login.jsp page using mapping.forwared(), here it is not going to filter. directly the login.jsp page is loaded with new token, but controller didnt came to filter. for first request itself  it is showing that warning of token missing.

Comment: If you want the filter to be invoked for forward too, then you need to configure that in the filter mapping - the 4 possible values are REQUEST,ERROR,FORWARD,INCLUDE.